# GCP ssh via identity access proxy fails locally but not via cloud shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine, google-iap

I am trying to SSH into a Compute Engine VM that has only a private IP.

I am trying to use IAP to access it. I can SSH using cloud shell just fine, but I'd like to be able to use `gcloud` to do the same, but I get the following error when trying to connect.

```
[21:53] atte@x1:terraform $ gcloud compute ssh bastion --project=my-project
External IP address was not found; defaulting to using IAP tunneling.
kex_exchange_identification: banner line contains invalid characters
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

Here is the relevant firewall configuration enabling IAP access

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "my_vpc_fw_allow_iap" {
    project = google_project.project.name
    name = "${google_compute_network.my_vpc.name}-allow-iap"
    network = google_compute_network.my_vpc.name

    allow {
        protocol = "tcp"
    }

    source_ranges = ["35.235.240.0/20"]
}
```

(I also have a rule enabling SSH ingress from everywhere, although the above should be enough?) and here is my Compute Engine instance

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "bastion" {
    name = "bastion"
    project = google_project.project.project_id
    machine_type = "f1-micro"
    zone = var.zone

    boot_disk {
        initialize_params {
          image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
        }
    }

    network_interface {
      subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.my_vpc_subnet1.self_link
    }

    metadata = {
        enable-oslogin = "TRUE"
    }

    # tags = ["iap-access"]
    deletion_protection = false
}
```

I am using a project owner account to try to SSH, so I don't see how it would be a credential issue.

Comment: `kex_exchange_identification: banner line contains invalid characters` seems to indicate that establishing the IAP-TCP tunnel worked, but establishing an SSH connection failed. 
Does your local `~/.ssh/config` contain any settings that might interfere?

Comment: You might want to check the documentation on [Connecting to instances that do not have external IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#sshbetweeninstances) since you are using a private IP. Also, can you rerun the ssh command with the `--troubleshoot` option?

Comment: @JohannesPassing there are no settings in the config that interfere

Comment: @AlexG 
VM status: 1 issue(s) found.

The VM may not be running. Try restarting it. If this doesn't work, the VM may be in a panic state.

Comment: @AlexG no other errors. I can still SSH using the google cloud web interface so the machine is up and running

Comment: Did you follow the [IAP TCP forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#gcloud) documentation?

Comment: @AlexG yes, ingress from `35.235.240.0/20` is allowed, and I am using the owner account which has sufficient permissions.

Comment: I tried to replicate your configuration but did not receive any error when doing so. As commented by Johannes, the issue might be in your instance SSH configuration.